# How to open Mac Keynote presentations on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, mac, openoffice, presentations, iwork-keynote

How to open Mac Keynote presentations on Ubuntu? Can it be imported to Impress?

Answer (score 23):

Create an iCloud account (https://www.icloud.com). Its free. Upload the keynote presentation. Once uploaded, you can click on the file and "download a copy" the file as either a PDF, PPT. or a key file.

Comment: You can also continue editing it, which is sweet.

Comment: iCloud is indeed free, until you take 15GB of videos on your iPad and fill the space.  Thankfully, deleting a few videos will allow converting some keynote presentations again :-)

Answer (score 13):

There is an online conversion service at http://www.zamzar.com/ (assuming that your file does not contain confidential information ...)

Comment: zamzar insists on emailing the converted file to you.

Comment: @Kinjal Dixit, not any more. But there is a limit of maximum two conversions per day - unless you are willing to pay.

Answer (score 0):

[OneClick macOS Simple KVM](https://github.com/notAperson535/OneClick-macOS-Simple-KVM) supports running graphical apps, including Final Cut Pro and XCode.

Answer (score -1):

You can export it as a PowerPoint, which may be open-able by Impress.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm on Ubuntu, I don't have access to Keynote.

Comment: Can you get the author to export it for you?

Comment: Thanks, there are some sites that allow to convert to PowerPoint format too. But these are not the options I'm looking for.